# Заменить окончания слов (c#)

Tags: c#

Пользователь вводит текст. Если слово заканчивается на гласную, то заменить окончание на "program"(c #)

Comment: Это хорошо, что у вас есть задание. Но в чем вопрос?

Comment: регулярные выражения

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пожалуйста!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("vvedi stroku: ");
        string stroka = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] massiv1 = { "а", "о", "и", "е", "ё", "э", "ы", "у", "ю", "я" };
        foreach (var bukvi in massiv1)
        {
            if (stroka.EndsWith(bukvi))
            {
                string newstroka = stroka.Replace(stroka.Substring(stroka.Length - 1), "program");
                Console.WriteLine(newstroka);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Только это программа меняет окончание только в  одном слове, которое кончается на гласную, а именно - в последнем слове. Как изменить так, чтобы менялись окончания всех слов в строке, которые кончаются на гласную,?